# Blazor (Server) - Good Practice: Do i need a Controllers or is anything handled by Services

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to .net, C# and currently write my first Blazor(servcer-side) app.
Later i want to migrate to Blazor webassembly..

However, I came to the question, do I need controllers? 
I know Controllers in the form of NestJS - that Controllers handle http requests and use Services for data exchange and other tasks.

But because currently everything is handled server-side no http requests are made..
So I can't think of a case, where this (division) could come handy..

Do i misunderstand or oversee something?

And furthermore, are Controllers used in WebAssembly Blazor apps, where actual http requests are made?

Because here I can imagine that such a division is advantageous.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In most cases you can design your application to run in either mode.  You build two slightly different data pipelines, one using APIs and the other direct.  The Web Assembly pipeline uses the Server data pipeline, but with a API data broker at the Web Assembly end, and a API controller at the other.

Comment: Do _you_ want to migrate to WebAssembly as a dev or do you want to migrate your App?  Makes a difference.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I am planning to build the app fully first only with Blazor server side  and then migrate when needed or some cases occour.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis That was also what i understood. So no need for controllers now, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Every time you browse to a website, you are making an http request. Asp.Net has two main ways of processing the request and returning a response:

- Pages (Blazor)
- Controllers (e.g. MVC, or api controllers)

You can use either one of these approaches alone, or you can run them both together. A simplified description of the server-side Blazor pipeline:

- Decide which page the request is routed to
- Deserialize the body and query parameters, based on the C# class for that page
- Instantiate the page
- Execute the handler method on the page
- **Render the page**
- **Return the rendered page as a response**

The Controller pipeline is very similar:

- Decide which controller+action the request is routed to
- Deserialize the body and query parameters, based on the C# controller and action
- Instantiate the controller
- Execute the action (this might involve rendering a page)
- Return the result of the action (this could be html, or it could be json)

If all you are ever doing is rendering pages server-side and interacting with them, then you can do this entirely through Blazor, with no need for controllers. This is not the main selling point of Blazor, server-side rendering has been around for a while. The interesting part is that you can change the hosting model to Client-side and still achieve this! The client maintains a connection to the server, and sends events when the user interacts with pages or components, but Blazor handles all the details for you. This does come with overhead - every time something on the UI needs to be updated, the server has to send that UI to the client. If you want to remove that overhead, and just send the raw data, then you would need to create api controllers.

I suggest reading through these pages for more information:

- [Architecture comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/architecture-comparison)
- [Hosting models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/hosting-models)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and clarifying when .net known controllers are used. 
Unfortunately I don't seem to miss something, but it doesn't talk about controllers in the sense of my question. 




Also, your last sentences suggest that I can switch with a server-rendered app from the model: 
- Receive events and send changes in the DOM to the client accordingly.
to the model:
- Receive events and send pure data to the client, which then renders it.


However, this is not the case... is it? 
To do so, Webassembly client-rendered app is needed.. right?

Comment: @CAoT client-side implies web assembly. Blazor is not transpiled to Javascript.

Comment: To clarify the last part, you can create a client side app that explicitly uses http requests to get data from the server, instead of letting Blazor handle it implicitly. For this scenario, you need to create the corresponding API endpoints on the server using controllers

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if you query your data via api controllers even for Blazor Server (they could be implemented inside Blazor Server project) so that it'd be much easier to migrate from server to wasm

I just created a Blazor server app and I injected the DAL into each component (instead of using api controllers) cause it was much faster to develop but when I tried to migrate to wasm it was very hard because I'll have to rewrite most of it